# Getting history of branch with merges

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Lets say we have a branch master, and I want to see a the history of what the master branch have been pointing to. Usually I can do this with `git log --first-parent`. But let's say we have another branch staging. Staging merges in master, and then someone on master fast forward merges staging. Now we can no longer get a history of what master used to point to by only following the first parent. The problem is that we now have a commit in master's history where the true history of master is found by following the second parent.

It seems to me like we could still get that history, as long the default merge message is used. The method would be: Starting at some commit, unless the commit message is "Merge branch master...", follow first parent; if commit message is "Merge branch master", then follow only second parent.

Is there a way to do this with different options to `git log`? In general what is the easiest way in git to construct a log by looking at each commit and based on that choosing to show it, not show it, and which parent to follow? Can this be done by git itself or should I look into for example a git library for python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to [choose the parent to follow] with different options to `git log`?

No.

> In general what is the easiest way in git to construct a log by looking at each commit and based on that choosing to show it, not show it, and which parent to follow? Can this be done by git itself or should I look into for example a git library for python?

That's certainly an option.  Alternatively, you can download the Git repository for Git and experiment with adding code to it.  The last (slowest to run, but easiest to write) option is to use something like `git rev-list --parents`, read the hash IDs that this prints, and write your own variant of `git log` in shell script or similar.